# Apt-getting python-matplotlib for multiple python versions

Tags: python, apt

I have two different versions of python running on the server, 2.4 (default) and 2.5. 
Python-matplotlib is install via apt-get for 2.4. I want to install it also for 2.5, but apt-get install says that it is already installed. How do I specify that the install target should be the non-default python version.

Comment: which distribution and which version?

Comment: Just curious, why not stick with 2.5 instead of 2.4?  Is there a specific feature that will break in 2.5?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [EasyInstall](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall), to install packages native to each Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Link python command so that "python --version" shows the version you want matplotlib to be installed for.
Manually compile and install matplotlib.
Relink python command back to previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Python modules need to be installed for each python version separately. Debian has support for multiple-python modules in one package (via `python-support` and `python-central`), but supported python version must be declared at build time. `python-matplotlib` package in `squeeze` has `Python-Version: 2.4, 2.5`, so it contains support for python2.5. Either you are using older distribution or you are doing something wrong.